# Salesforce Community: Adding Asset files to a change set and validating without errors

Tags: deployment, lightning-community, change-set, community-builder

I am in the process of migrating a salesforce community from the dev sandbox to full sandbox. I have successfully created and validated all required Components Available in Change Set, (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=changesets_about_components.htm&type=5), except the **asset file component**. After adding the Asset file component to my change set and uploading, I get the **"No managing workspace specified"** error when I try to validate and the validation fails.
Any pointers on what I might be missing or the correct process to add asset files to change sets and successfully validate and deploy will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Maumau

Comment: Can you check where the assets are being used in the community?Can you check if these are part of the Unsupported Settings and Features listed in https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_migrate_considerations.htm&type=5#unsupported  . If so, you need to remove the assets file from the change set and then manually upload them once the changeset is validated?

Comment: Thanks Swetha. I had to do a manual upload.

Comment: Thanks for confirming @MauMau. I have posted this information as an answer so that others facing the same issue might find it helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to check where the assets are being used in the community. In case these are part of the Unsupported Settings and Features listed in [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_migrate_considerations.htm&type=5#unsupported), you need to remove the assets file from the changeset and then manually upload them once the changeset is validated.

Copying unsupported from documentation

> - Navigational and featured topics
> - Audience targeting
> - Dashboards and engagement
> - Recommendation images
> - Branding panel images in Experience Builder
>
> The following Administration settings in Experience Workspaces:
>
> - The Account field in the Registration section of the Login and Registration area
> - The Select which login options to display option in the Login section of the Login and Registration area
> - The Settings area
> - The Rich Publisher Apps area